# How to move a object by titling the screen in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have his code for making movemnt of the object through horizontal postion.

```
#define kAccelerationSpeed 10
#define kAccelerometerFrequency 200


-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{


    CGPoint pt =  thePlayer.position ;
    CGFloat accel = acceleration.x * kAccelerationSpeed;
    pt = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:pt];


        pt = ccp (pt.x+accel>0 , yLocationOfPlayer+accel<768 );


}
```

in init statment

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {
 [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:(1.0 / kAccelerometerFrequency)];
        [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
    }
```

whats wrong with the above code,it is not working,when i tilt the screen,it is not making any movemnt for the "theplayer" object.please help me to do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does move the object? I don't see any code for that? Also, that 10 pixels for the +/- maximal acceleration doesn't very convincing...

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for the quick reply, pt = ccp (pt.x+accel>0 , yLocationOfPlayer+accel<768 ); is this enough to move the thepalyer object?. am newbe in cocos2d ,postion.x.the accelartion speed > 0 ,it will moves o the left side,this is the logic.if any eroor ,please help me

Comment: @H2CO3 i add this code also but it is not woking id move =  [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:CGPointMake(pt.x+accel>0 , yLocationOfPlayer+accel<768)];
    [thePlayer runAction:move];

Answer (score 0):

you're not assigning the position of the player sprite. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"position before = %@", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:thePlayer.position]);
thePlayer.position = ccp (pt.x+accel>0 , yLocationOfPlayer+accel<768 );     
NSLog(@"position after = %@", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:thePlayer.position]);
```

The logging will help you to determine if 1) the delegate method is getting fired and 2) the positions are as you are expecting.

Comment: it is not working,i alredy tried,i already assinged theplayer.postion in  CGPoint pt =  thePlayer.position ;

Comment: "CGPoint pt = thePlayer.position" assigns the position to pt - it doesn't do anything with the actual "thePlayer" object.

Comment: put some logging around it and see what is going on - i updated my answer with logging statements

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your delegates are setup to report accelerometer information?  Are you also assigning thePlayer.position in the accelerometer callback?  I can't recall why but I do recall trying assignment within the callback and the results were rather stuttered and problematic.  The solution for me was to have a variable the accelerometer delegate call will modify and assign the position of thePlayer inside of a tick script based on the variable update in the delegate callback.